# Sorting factors in more than 2 ordinal variables

Tags: r, syntax, ordinal

I have a question in regards to comparing factors in more than 3 ordinal variables.

I have tried this on Rstudio, and on Datacamp. After setting a specific order in dealing with more than 2 ordinal variables (low, medium, high), when comparing high and medium, why does "high > medium" yield FALSE?

```
temperature_vector <- c("High", "Low", "High","Low", "Medium")
factor_temperature_vector <- factor(temperature_vector, order = TRUE, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))
factor_temperature_vector 

#The above line returns:
#[1] High   Low    High   Low    Medium
#Levels: Low < Medium < High

high <- temperature_vector[1]
medium <- temperature_vector[5]
low <- temperature_vector[2]

high > low #returns FALSE

high > medium #returns FALSE. Why?
```

Solved:

Need to compare factors instead of variables:

```
high <- **factor_**temperature_vector[1]
medium <- **factor_**temperature_vector[5]
low <- **factor_**temperature_vector[2]
```

Comment: You are comparing character string where the ordering is based on alphabetic order

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if base on alphabetical order, both statements should be TRUE?

Comment: Both should be `FALSE` `"h" > "m"#
[1] FALSE`

Comment: Okay thank you. I get it now. If I want to compare them, I need to compare the factors, not the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment to identifiers are from `character` vector, instead of the `factor` vector.  For `character` strings, the ordering is alphabetic order where `h` is less than `m`

```
high <- factor_temperature_vector[1]
medium <- factor_temperature_vector[5]
low <- factor_temperature_vector[2]

high > low
#[1] TRUE
high > medium
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Got it, Thanks!!